# How to generate JUnit Test case in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am practising JUnit test cases and currently working on a problem which is as follows:

- To read HTML from any website say "http://www.google.com" ( Candidate can use any API of inbuilt APIs in Java like URLConnection ).
- Print on console the HTML from the URL above and save it to a file ( web-content.txt) in local machine.
- Write JUnit test cases for the above program.

I've successfully achieved first steps but when I am running JUnit Test Case its showing Failure.

**ReadFile.java**

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ReadFile 
{
    static void display(String input,OutputStream fos)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(input);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            int data=0;
            while((data=reader.read())!=-1)
            {
                System.out.print((char)data);
                fos.write((char)data);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input =null;
        FileOutputStream fos =null;
        System.out.println("Please enter any url");
        try
        {
            input = reader.readLine();
            fos = new FileOutputStream("src/web-context.txt");
            display(input,fos);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**ReadFileTest.java**

```
package com.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ReadFileTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ReadFile.display("http://google.co.in", baos);
        assertTrue(baos.toString().contains("http://google.co.in"));
    }

}
```

I am getting following error while running JUnit Test in Eclipse:

> java.lang.AssertionError
>   java.lang.AssertionError at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86) at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41) at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52) at com.test.ReadFileTest.test(ReadFileTest.java:15) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown

I want that the JUnit Test Case will return true.

Comment: What exception you have?

Comment: Please share the entire error log and what is the expected output.

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
 at com.sudhir.ReadFileTest.test(ReadFileTest.java:15)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown 

 i want that the JUnit Test Case will return true

Comment: I think that your baos.toString() produce a NullPointerException

Comment: The assertion error means that your assertTrue came out false.  It doesn't give you much info.  You need to find out what baos.toString() actually returned.  Asserts take a "String" parameter that is printed when they fail, so you probably want the assertTrue a string like "baos was not as expected, instead it was:"+baos.toString() (That string should be the first parameter of the assert, your existing parameter should be the second).

Comment: I think the page "http://google.co.in" does not contain the text "http://google.co.in" but see in debug mode for example, what is being returned.

Comment: Also, although it wouldn't be helpful here, you typically paste the entire stack trace of the error into the StackOverflow question.  Stack traces contain an AMAZING amount of info and you should always include them... and if  you don't already, learn how to read them.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Good that you got the answer. Please be gentle enough to share the same or mark from already shared the one that worked. :)

Comment: Sudhir, please could I trouble you to add in your stack trace or exception into this question, as if you had edited your question on the same day you asked this question. That is better preserved in the question, since it seems to be related to the problem you experienced, and may well be useful for a future reader. They are not likely to find it in the comments. Once you have made this edit, please ping me with `@halfer` and I will undownvote. Thank you!

Comment: @halfer edited my question with error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's not working here is :

```
assertTrue(baos.toString().contains("http://google.co.in"));
```

and what would work is

```
assertTrue(baos.toString().contains("google.co.in")); // note the difference
```

Answer (score 0):

Make something like that:

```
static String display(String input) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(input);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        int data = 0;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((data = reader.read()) != -1) {
            builder.append((char) data);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't know why you use ByteArrayOutputStream

And now for your test case:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String data = ReadFile.display("http://google.co.in");
    assertTrue(data != null);
    assertTrue(data.contains("http://google.co.in"));
}
```